# Identify a hardware feature on the rear side of the case of a Dell Precision workstation

Tags: case, workstation, case-layout

I recently bought a Dell Precision 3630 Tower. On the rear side of the case, I see 2 black slidable tabs, with lock and unlock iconography. They appear to do nothing (to me) when I slide them.

[image]

[image: Zoomed in view of the same]

Can someone tell me what they are supposed to be for?

ETA:
I found this on Dell's Website, which says that these are "***PSU hinge release latch***". I still don't know what these are for.

[image]

Comment: Did you not get a user manual?

Comment: nope. I don't think there was one in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On the rear side of the case, I see 2 black slidable tabs, with lock and unlock iconography.

> [image]
>
> 11. PSU hinge release latch

...

> 18. PSU hinge release latch

Source [Precision Tower 3630 Setup and Specifications Guide](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/precision-3630-workstation/prec_3630_specifications_manual/back-view?guid=guid-276a3616-7ac3-4d59-97bc-414de22c1d89&lang=en-us)

---

#### So what is a PSU hinge release latch?

It allows you to rotate the PSU in preparation for [removing it](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/precision-3630-workstation/prec_3630_service_manual/removing-the-power-supply-unit?guid=guid-232f3655-1a12-4046-b457-575beb7c0eb5&lang=en-us)

[image]

Source [Precision Tower 3630 Service Manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/precision-3630-workstation/prec_3630_service_manual/opening-the-psu-hinge?guid=guid-43702315-375d-41d7-bb24-912bf1197b8a&lang=en-us)